# SPARQL Delete Query

Tags: sparql, rdf, turtle-rdf, triples

I have been searching everywhere for a way to delete only duplicate triples, however, I haven't been successfully in finding  solution.

For example if I had the following triple store

```
ex:Bob rdf:type dbo:Person. 
ex:Bob rdf:type dbo:Person. 
ex:Bob rdf:type dbo:Person.
```

And I use the following delete query

```
DELETE {ex:Bob rdf:type dbo:Person.}
```

All triples will be removed, however, the output I require is below:

```
ex:Bob rdf:type dbo:Person.
```

I have tried using select queries with the limit set but this won't work if there exist more than one set of triples within the triplestore.

Thank you for any help provided.

Comment: What is your triplestore? Allegrograph? Normslly, triples witj same s, p, o "colapse" into one triple, unless they belong to diffetent named graphs.

Comment: Agreeing with @StanislavKralin in that all RDF stores that I know of, due to RDf theory, will de-duplicate identical triples. To get repeated triples from one store, you must have context (Named Graph) that is different between triples.